# What to do if I disagree with a moderator decision?

Tags: support, moderators, specific-flag

I have a problem with an insulting comment on a [post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20752/monetizing-se-bounties) which I flagged two times as offensive and not constructive, but the moderators did not delete it.

What is the next level where I can report my complaint?

Comment: If this is the question about handling this one particular flag, you should add ([meta-tag:specific-flag]) tag. If you want to ask about more general issue stated in the title, then this tag is not suitable. But I would recommend removing the link, since it will distract from the main question. (You can explain that you flagged some comment even without explicitly linking to the particular comment.)

Comment: For example, I would upvote the general question. (Since this might be a useful information.) I might downvote the question about particular flag. (I do not agree that it is offensive. Maybe it can be called non-constructive, but it is probably not bad enough for flagging.) The way the question is phrased I am not sure whether you are asking the general question or you want to discuss this specific instance. So I am not sure how to vote.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I think the answer is the same to both issues and anyways I would like to know about both solutions.

Comment: I think that advice from [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28867/what-recourse-do-i-have-if-i-believe-a-moderator-has-abused-his-her-privileges/28869#28869) is very reasonable: *"It's often best for you to try to work things out at as low a level as possible."* (The post is about a more serious isue that just handling flags.)

Comment: Are we talking about the comment that (currently) has 11 upvotes?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes.

Comment: Well, emcor, that can be interpreted as an indication of the community viewpoint on the comment. We wouldn't want the moderators to act contrary to the standards of the community, would we?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I dont agree that the fact that a certain group of people upvotes a comment can deprive me of my human rights not to be offended in public. There has been a recent [judgment](http://rt.com/news/267700-delfi-comments-echr-censorship/) by the European Court of Human Rights stating that I am entitled to indemnity if I feel my reputation is harmed through an online comment. I will contact the next level at SE first, but I do have a lawyer to dismiss any unlawful activity on SE and grant me a significant amount of indemnity if my plea is refused.

Comment: IANAL, but I seriously doubt that any court has ever stated that an individual is entitled to anything simply because the individual *feels* his or her reputation has been harmed.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You ought to be joking with this "community viewpoint" comment. This is a terrible line of argument and could be used to justify all kinds of abuse and discrimination, here and especially elsewhere. (This is not altered by the fact that I personally consider the specific comment in question as harmless in its intent.)

Comment: On main, I would have agreed that an analogous comment would be unconstructive and borderline rude. On meta, not so much. This is the place to voice opinion.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes on this meta-post. It is a completely fine question to ask what to do when one disagrees with moderators.

Comment: "Insulting"? The comment in question is supposed to be insulting? How?

Comment: @emcor Please don't be ridiculous. Even in that biased news report it's explicitly written "Today’s decision doesn’t have any direct legal effect. It simply finds that Estonia’s laws on site liability aren’t incompatible with the ECHR. It doesn’t directly require any change in national or EU law." How you can interpret that decision as you having a human right not to be offended in public is beyond my comprehension.

Comment: I agree with you, the comment is rude, however he isn't attacking you so it doesn't even count as ad hominem. You shouldn't be hurt by the comment, he is only commenting on the validity of the idea.

Comment: @quid "...  especially elsewhere." If the community was determining the truth, the earth would probably still be flat ;).

Comment: FYI: The comment under consideration has been deleted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a [contact us](https://math.stackexchange.com/contact) link at the bottom of every page that will allow you to contact SE directly. Moderators do not have access to messages sent this way, although SE staff may reveal certain details if/when they follow up with us.

I have doubts that they will involve themselves too much in the moderation of comments, but I have been wrong before. On the other hand, if enough regular users flag a comment ([the threshold appears to be](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138119/if-you-really-want-to-reduce-the-snark-level#comment387982_138119) $3 + \lfloor \frac {\mathrm {score}} 3 \rfloor$, with possible reductions due to content) it will be deleted.

Comment: Before I accept this as answer, I will try out the link...

Comment: I contacted them...

Answer (score 3):

I will just echo what Arthur said. I have flagged content before and have had the flags rejected. I have then contacted SE directly and every time I did I had the content removed. From personal experience, I would say that this is a good way to go.

Note, if your complaint is also rejected from the higher-ups, then I simply just wouldn't worry about it. I don't think that there is a need to contact SE everytime the moderators don't come down on your side. Often I think it is better to just let it go.

If you want to try something between flagging and contacting SE directly, then you can try to catch a moderator in chat. Here you might get a nicer response and you might be able to hear their side.

Comment: +1 for the "Often I think it is better to just let it go."

Comment: I did let go many flags, but I was really unhappy with this one because they had deleted my comments I sent as defense, but not the comment in question. How can I contact the moderators in chat?

Comment: @emcor: I am not sure how you can contact the moderators in chat. In the past I have been lucky and caught a moderator who coincidentally happened to be in chat.

Comment: The name of the chat room [Math Mods' Office](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20352/math-mods-office) suggests that there is a real possibility of finding a mod in that room. @emcor

Comment: @1999: Great. I didn't know about this!